# Как задать время создания экземпляра BaseModel в pydantic

Tags: python, pydantic

Распаршиваю json в BaseModel от pydantic. Нужен элегантный способ задать время создания экземпляра класса. Пока на уме только опциональное поле и доп метод, но выглядит как костыль.

```py
class Test(BaseModel):
    name: str
    create_time: Optional[datetime]

    def set_create_time(self) -> None:
        self.create_time = datetime.now()
```

Update:

Данный костыль можно усовершенствовать, чтобы вызов не переносить на отдельную строку.

```py
class Test(BaseModel):
    name: str
    create_time: Optional[datetime]

    def set_create_time(self) -> BaseModel:
        self.create_time = datetime.now()
        return self
```

Т.е.

```py
test = Test.parse_obj(data).set_create_time()
```

Вместо

```py
test = Test.parse_obj(data)
test.set_create_time()
```

Comment: А просто какой-нибудь [default_factory](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#field-with-dynamic-default-value) задать не?

Comment: @andreymal , спасибо именно такое решение я и искал

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать  `model_post_init()` - метод, выполняющийся при создании экземпляра класса после стандартного `__init__()`
Ниже - пример для часового пояса UTC:

```
    class Test(BaseModel):
        name: str
        create_time: Optional[datetime]

        def model_post_init(self, __context: Any) -> None:
            self.create_time = datetime.now(UTC)
```